# How to check if a file is already opened in tcl

Tags: file-io, tcl

I have a tcl procedure where i opened a file, create if not exist for writing. Now i am logging some puts statement in it for my debugging. Now at the end of this proc, i close the file. But in the middle i am calling another proc and i need to write something into this opened file in that proc as well. So i want to do something like this:

```
proc ::myproc {args} { 
  set fp [open "C:\\log.txt" w+];
  puts $fp "Checkpoint 1";
  set retVal [::myprocII];
  puts $fp "Checkpoint 2";
  close $fp;
  return 1;
}

proc ::myprocII {} {
  set fp [open "C:\\log.txt" w+];
  puts $fp "Checkpoint 3";
  close $fp;
  return 1;
}
```

So isn't it a cause of error or exception as i open the same file in myprocII and log data and close it. And then i am still logging the data in my calling proc myproc even after i close the file in myprocII. I tried to test this but since i am running it from a batch file, the window closes before i can figure out what the error is.

So I wanted to know if this is correct or if not than how can i keep on appending the data in same log file from different procedures.

Comment: Tcl itself doesn't provide a mechanism for doing the test you ask for (and it'd be rather difficult to implement on Windows, as I don't think there's an equivalent of the POSIX `fstat()` call).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options:

- Use 1 file descriptor, close that at the end of your program.

  ```
  proc log {data} {
      global logfd
      if {![info exists logfd] || $logfd == ""} {
          set logfd [open {C:\log.txt} w]
      }
      puts $logfd $data
  }

  # before you exit, close it:
  catch {close $::logfd}
  ```

  Tcl should close the file on exit on it's own when the program terminates.
- Open/Close the file for each write. Only useful in append mode

  ```
  proc log {data} {
      set fd [open {C:\log.txt} a]
      catch {
          puts $fd $data
      } res opt
      close $fd
      return -options $opt $res
  }
  ```

  This is not the most performant solution, but it is clean.
- Use some hacks

  ```
  rename open _open
  rename close _close
  proc open {path args} {
     global sharedfd
     if {$path eq {C:\log.txt}} {
         if {[info exists sharedfd] && [dict exists $sharedfd fd]} {
             dict incr sharedfd refcount
             return [dict get $sharedfd fd]
         } else {
             set fd [_open $path {*}$args]
             dict set sharedfd fd $fd
             dict set sharedfd refcount 1
             return $fd
         }
     }
     return [_open $path {*}$args]
  }

  proc close {fd args} {
      global sharedfd
      if {[info exists sharedfd] 
              && [dict exists $sharedfd fd] 
              && [dict get $sharedfd fd] eq $fd} {
          dict incr sharedfd refcount -1
          if {[dict get $sharedfd refcount] <= 0} {
             _close $fd
             unset sharedfd
          }
          return
      }
      _close $fd {*}$args
  }
  ```

  Returns the same fd for `C:\log.txt` if it is already open, keeps a refcounter, closes the channel when the refcount is 0.
  Be aware that this is a hack. You should probably not modify the standard commands.

Comment: Logs should _always_ be written in append mode. On proper POSIX systems, this makes the OS ensure that writes can't overlap, even if the log is being written to from multiple processes.

Comment: Also, option 1 is the one that professional logging systems use. (They also tweak the buffering parameters.)